# React middle ware for fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my react.js based application where all ajax call are made by `fetch`. I would like to write some middle ware that allow me handle all redirection (response with status code 302)

I did following:in main start file `window.fetch` was overrided 
(note I put `console.log('some number')` in each fetch to see the flow)

```
const fetch = window.fetch
window.fetch = function() {
return Promise.resolve(fetch.apply(window, arguments)).then((response) =>  {
    console.log("middleware is working")
    console.log(arguments)
    console.log('1')
    if (response.status == '302') {
        window.location.replace("/login");
    }
})
}

fetch("/adminInitData", {credentials: 'same-origin'})
.then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log("3")
    });
}).catch(()=> {
   some code
});

const destination = document.querySelector("#container");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppAdmin/>
  </Provider>,
destination
);
```

In one of react component I have the following `fetch`

```
fetch(urls.ADMIN_ORDER_ALL_SHOT,
        {credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'},
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("2")
            response.json().then((data) => {
                if (response.status == '200'){
                    this.setBoxStatus(data)
                }
            });
        }).catch((e)=> {
        console.log('exception in "get" url '+ urls.ADMIN_AVAILABLE_BOX_LIST + " exception= " +e)
    })
```

When this code was executed the following information was shown in console

[image]

Can you explain me the following:
1) why exception appear and how to fix it?
2) why my overrided fetch is not call in main file where fetch to address `/adminInitData` was call?

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 mistakes:
1) to fix error we have to to return response from override `window.fetch`
2) to recognize redirect we have to check `response.redirected` but not `response.status`

```
const fetch = window.fetch
window.fetch = function() {
return Promise.resolve(fetch.apply(window, arguments).then((response) =>  {
    if (response.redirected == true) {
        window.location.replace("/login");
    }
    return response;
})).catch((e)=> {
    console.log('Fetch exception:'  + e)
})
}
```